# mysql order by multiple value in specific order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There is one table called projects with their details. 
projects

```
id | status |name 
1  | Red | Prj1
2| Amber | Prj2
3| Green | Prj3
4| RED | Prj4
5|Completed  | Prj5
6|Amber  | Prj6
7|Green  | Prj7
5|Completed  | Prj8
```

Using mysql-can I arrange in specific order.
Result needed show all projects in Red at first place than Green and Amber after that completed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an expression in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when status = 'red' then 1 when status = 'green' then 2 else 3 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status,'Completed,Amber,Green,Red') DESC
```

Comment: @ Alex #1305 - FUNCTION DEV.FIND_IN_INDEX does not exist getting this error